# CS50's speller unable to handle most basic words

Tags: c, dictionary, cs50

```
// Implements a dictionary's functionality

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <strings.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include "dictionary.h"

// Represents a node in a hash table
typedef struct node
{
   char word[LENGTH + 1];
   struct node *next;
}
node;

// Number of buckets in hash table
const unsigned int N = 26;

// Hash table
node *table[N];

//num of words
int NumOfWords = 0;

// Returns true if word is in dictionary else false
bool check(const char *word)
{
   node *word_checker = malloc(sizeof(node));
   int hash_position = hash(word);
   word_checker = table[hash_position];
   while(word_checker != NULL)
   {
       if( strcasecmp(word_checker->word, word) == 0)
       {
           free(word_checker);
           return true;
       }
       word_checker = word_checker->next;
   }
   return false;
}

// Hashes word to a number
unsigned int hash(const char *word)
{
   int hash_index = 0;
   for(int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++)
   {
       if(isalpha(word[i]))
       {
            hash_index += word[i];
       }
   }
   return hash_index % N;
}

// Loads dictionary into memory, returning true if successful else false
bool load(const char *dictionary)
{
   char word[LENGTH + 1];
   FILE *file = fopen(dictionary, "r");
   if(file == NULL)
   {
       return 1;
   }
   while(fscanf(file, "%s", word) != EOF)
   {
       node *new_node = malloc(sizeof(node));
       if(new_node == NULL)
       {
           return false;
       }
       strcpy(new_node ->word, word);
       new_node ->next = NULL;
       int index = hash(word);
       if(table[index] == NULL)
       {
           table[index] = new_node;
       }
       else
       {
           new_node ->next = table[index];
           table[index] ->next = new_node;
       }
       NumOfWords++;
   }
   fclose(file);
   return true;
}

// Returns number of words in dictionary if loaded else 0 if not yet loaded
unsigned int size(void)
{
   return NumOfWords;
}

// Unloads dictionary from memory, returning true if successful else false
bool unload(void)
{
   for(int i = 0; i < N; i++)
   {
       node *cursor = NULL;
       cursor = table[i];
       while (cursor != NULL)
       {
           node *tmp = cursor;
           cursor = cursor->next;
           free(tmp);
       }
   }
   return true;
}
```

> error messages are: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/pabnG.png

also, valgrind says invalid read of size 8 on line 110 (cursor = cursor->next;)
It also checks the words case sensitively which is not what I wanted. I have tried using strcasecmp but to no avail.
I'm still new to stackoverflow so please excuse some minor mistakes in formatting.

Comment: You should include the errors as text in the question, and not as an image.

Comment: Added errors as text as well.

Comment: @Revealed Where are the errors as text? I only see a link to some image.